# How to setup angular.io testing using mocha

Tags: angular, mocha.js, angular-test

i've been trying to find solutions for a long time, i've tried many ways found on the internet but they just don't work because API is either outdated or packages are no longer supported.

What i'm trying is to make angular test without the need of any browser since the tests have to be running on a server that cannot have any browser, i cannot make use of `PhantomJS` because that is no longer maintained and i need to find a way to make this work on `mocha` because the server side of my application is already doing tests on `mocha`, so for reducing the amount of tools for testings i want this to be one on `mocha` as well.

Please.. does someone know a way to run `angular` tests on mocha?.. if not, what other tool could there be that does not make use of a browser for `angular`?

Comment: Can't you run Google Chrome or Firefox in headless mode on the server?

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt the server doesn't have either `chrome` or `firefox`, we are trying not to install any additional software to the server, but if we have to.. that has to be the last option

Comment: Ah, I get it. Just a thought: If I recall correctly PhantomJS also needs stuff to be installed on the machine, so maybe headless chrome/firefox is not _that_ different.

Comment: @SimonGroenewolt it isn't as different like you mentioned, we once considered `PhantomJS` but yet again we are trying to use as few tools as possible, also `PhantomJS` is no longer maintained so if we are to install an additional tool to the server, the tool must guarantee maintenance